# Is it truly impossible to cancel a draggable in flutter once it's started dragging?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I've been working on an app in Flutter for the past 2 or so weeks and I've got this problem where I cannot stop a draggable from dragging once the user has started dragging it. Is there any way at all to stop a draggable from code even if the user still keeps his finger down?

This is returning a custom widget which I have as the thing I am dragging:

```
return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
      child: Center(
        child: DragTarget<dynamic>(
            builder: (context, accepted, rejected){
                return Draggable(
                  maxSimultaneousDrags: getDrag(),
                  child: Container(height: 50, width: 50, color: Colors.pink,),
                  feedback: Container(height: 50, width: 50, color: Colors.pink,),
                  childWhenDragging: Container(height: 50, width: 50, color: Colors.yellowAccent,),
                );
            }
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: can you show some code? there should be a controller to the draggable which might help you.

Comment: @AnirudhBagri done

Comment: Please don't post the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62012644/anyway-to-cancel-currently-dragging-widget-in-flutter) multiple times.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore ok sorry my bad

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anyway to cancel currently dragging widget in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62012644/anyway-to-cancel-currently-dragging-widget-in-flutter)

Comment: @srikanth7785 sadly not